# Proving that a relation $(f,g)∈S$ iff $f(x)-g(x)\in\mathbb Z$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I have $S$ is relation on $A =\{\text{set of all functions }\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\}$ that  $(f,g)∈S$ iff $f(x)-g(x)\in\mathbb Z$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$

I start to prove it this way

Reflexive: for every $x\in\mathbb R$ we have  $f(x)-f(x)\in\mathbb Z$

Symmetric: for every $x\in\mathbb R$ if $f(x)-g(x)\in\mathbb Z$ then also $g(x)-f(x)\in\mathbb Z$

Transitive : for every $x\in\mathbb R$ if $f(x)-g(x)\in\mathbb Z$ and $g(x)-h(x)\in\mathbb Z$ then $f(x)-h(x)\in\mathbb Z$

Is that enough to prove equivalence relation  ?

and:

> How to find $|A/S|$?

Thanks

Comment: If that's enough? That's what being an equivalence relation *means*! How could it not be enough? I mean: those three statements is what you have to prove. Now, go and prove them. I don't understand your final question.

Comment: is $Z = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The OP is asking for the cardinality of the quotientspace, I guess.

Comment: @drhab I suppose you're right.

Comment: @drhab / JoséCarlosSantos Z=$ZZ$ yes and finding the cardinality of the quotientspace thats the final question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof that $S$ is an equivalence relation is okay but completeness is disputable.

For symmetry you should say something like: $f(x)-g(x)\in\mathbb Z\implies g(x)-f(x)=-(f(x)-g(x))\in\mathbb Z$.

By transitivity something like: $\cdots\implies f(x)-h(x)=(f(x)-g(x))+(g(x)-h(x))\in\mathbb Z$.

Hint for finding cardinality of $A/S$:

$A/S$ and $[0,1)^{\mathbb R}$ - i.e. the set of functions $\mathbb R\to[0,1)$ - are isomorphic.

Comment: so for $|A/S|$=$|[0,1)^{\mathbb R}|$= $א ^{|{\mathbb R}|}$=$א^א$ = $2^א$ ?

Comment: I guess so, but am not quite familiar with cardinal numbers. Concerning the isomorphism note that every equivalence class has a unique canonical representative $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies $\mathsf{im}f\subseteq[0,1)$.

Comment: okey i got it  thank you